# Why are $ a^{\log _{b} n} $ and $ n^{\log _{b} a} $ equivalent?

Tags: logarithms

I am reading about [master theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/master-theorem/) and it says that the number of leaves is $a^{\log _{b} n}$, and this part I can understand.

But then it immediately concludes that $$ a^{\log _{b} n} = n^{\log _{b} a} $$ which I am not getting. I verified that it is true by plugging in some values and also I tried to prove it by looking up properties of logatirthms but that didn't seem to help.

Can someone provide an explanation to why this is true?

Comment: Just take $\log_b$ of both sides.

Comment: Take $\log_b$ of both expressions.

Comment: So what I'm hearing, @lulu and saulspatz, is that you should take $\log_b$ of both sides, am I getting that right? :-) ¶ OK, just so this isn't just snark (however compassionate), let me point out that one way that it might occur to a student to do such a thing is that (a) there are logs aplenty here, and (b) if you take the log of $p^q$, then you get $q \log p$, so it's an easy way to kind of "homogenize" the expression by getting everything in terms of logs.  It's definitely something that comes with experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $\log_b$ of both:
$$\log_b(a^{\log_bn})=\log_b(n)\log_b(a)$$
$$\log_b(n^{\log_ba})=\log_b(a)\log_b(n)$$

Answer (score 4):

Are you familiar with the following: for any $c,d>1$: $d = c^{\log_c d}$. This follows from the definition of logarithm. I trust you also know the equation $e^{fg} = (e^f)^g$, for all positive $e,f,g$.

Thus:$$a^{\log_b n} = (b^{\log_b a})^{\log_b n}$$
$$= b^{\log_b a \log_b n} = (b^{\log_b n})^{\log_b a}$$
$$= n^{\log_b a}.$$

The first and last "$=$" following from the fact that
$d = c^{\log_c d}$ for any $c,d>1$, and the remaining "$=$" following from the fact that the equation $e^{fg} = (e^f)^g$ holds for all positive $e,f,g$.